# How to abort a spark transformation

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD containing item IDs.

I have a transformation which, for each ID, goes to the DB and gets the full item record.

In case the item was not found in the DB, `None` is returned.

However, sometime I get a timeout exception from the DB. In this case, I would like to abort the flatMap and not try accessing the DB for each item (I assume that if I got a timeout on one item, I will probably get the same exception on the rest of the items).

How can I do this with spark?

If I call `return` from within the catch clause I get an error "Return statements aren't allowed in Spark closures"

```
val rdd = sc.textFile(filePath, 1)
rdd.flatMap(id => {

    try {
            Some(getItemFromDB(id))
        } catch {
            case e: com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException =>
                //Here I would like to abort the flatMap transformation and retry after waitine a period of time
            case t: Throwable => None
        }
})
```

The only optimisation I can this of is to define an accumulator=0 which will hold a state of reading from the DB. If one item fails with a timeout, the accumulator is increase by 1. Before each time we read from the DB, we can check the sate of the accumulator and attempt to read only if accumulator=0.
However, if I remember correctly, spark accumulator are "write-only", so this won't really work.

Comment: I don't believe you can abort the transformation all together, but maybe you could use mapPartitions and a local variable that will hold the state of reading from db? That way, if you have n partitions, you will limit the number of access attempts to the DB to n if there is a timeout.

Comment: I ended up doing as you suggested. Thanks!